# How to plot data with 3 variables?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization

I have been trying to plot data with 3 variables. Data is something like this:

```
[month, country, count]
```

I tried to use `highcharts.js` bar graph with grouping on month but that does not convey the data visually. As you can imagine, there are multiple countries and 12 months for each makes the graph cluttered. Are there any other visualizations that can be used to plot such data?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to convey? What's the nature of the data? Would a stacked area chart work? https://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-stacked

Comment: How do you want the data to be visualized?

Comment: @AlfredoDelgado The data contains number of accidents in a country month wise. Also I have option for top 'k' countries where user provides the k. User can also provide 'all' as an option. Also the stacked graph wont work because of the same problem i.e there will be multiple countries

Comment: @Thomas Any way that does not clutter the visualization with ony few countries.

Comment: @VirajParimi How bad does a basic column chart look? Can you add a screenshot to your question? https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic

Comment: @AlfredoDelgado Sorry, cannot provide a screenshot now as I was working on it a week ago and removed the code to work on other data. But in the same column graph, imagine 100-150 countries rather than 4.

Comment: @VirajParimi I think it's reasonable to say that anybody that wants to look at that much data at once would prefer it in a tabular format :) That leaves building a UI where the user can select which countries and time periods they're interested in. At that level then the bar graph would work. Also, I haven't played with Highmaps but it looks pretty cool. I'm not sure how/if it'd be better than mapping the data with Google Maps, though. cf. https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/doubleclickzoomto